# How do they switch this function?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, cumulative-distribution-functions

This is a the walkthrough to acquire a derived distribution.  I don't get how they go from $\mathbf P(\frac{180}{y} \leq X)$ to $1 - F_X(\frac{180}{y})$.  Can someone explain to me?  Thanks!
[image: cdf]

Comment: Since $F_X(x)=\mathbb P\{X\leq x\},$ therefore $\mathbb P\{X>x\}=1-\mathbb P\{X\leq x\}=1-F_X(x)$.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!